# How do I send an email via mime-mail-ses which has a proper "from" name?

Tags: email, haskell, amazon-ses, mime-mail

The [`SES`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-mail-ses-0.4.0.0/docs/src/Network-Mail-Mime-SES.html#SES) data type has the `sesFrom` field. Everywhere on the Internet I see that I should write something like `"\"My Name\" <mymail@gmail.com>"` in order to display `My Name` in the "from" field. But when I put this into the `sesFrom` field I get

```
Not sent due to SESException {seStatus = Status {statusCode = 400, statusMessage = "Bad Request"}, seCode = "InvalidParameterValue", seMessage = "Missing '<'", seRequestId = "acf8bb7d-0440-11e8-94c8-45570c829243"}
```

I checked sources and all seems to be fine there. How do I set the `sesFrom` field, so a name is displayed?

Comment: Email messages have two "from" values -- the one in the message headers, which is the one that gets formatted with the display name -- and the envelope sender, which is in the form `<nospam@example.com>`.  `sesFrom` looks like it is specifying the latter.  I'm not familiar enough with your language to figure out where your message actually gets rendered into MIME format, with the headers, but perhaps this comment will give you a hint that you can work with -- there should be two places where the "sender" is set.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, `sesFrom` specifies the `Source` field which according to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendRawEmail.html) does contain some notion of "friendly name". But I do not see the rules there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it. Instead of writing `"\"My Name\" <mymail@gmail.com>" :: Address` and relying on `OverloadedStrings` one should write

```
Address (Just "Ny Name") "mymail@gmail.com"
```

I'd say the library should parse `"\"My Name\" <mymail@gmail.com>"` into that address, but whatever.